# JSF Rich Calendar

Tags: jsf, calendar, richfaces

I am trying to enable the time field in the calendar component (as shown in the attached snapshot).  I have set the date pattern value as below, but it doesn't enable the time field.

```
<rich:calendar value="#{calendarBean.selectedDate}" id="calendarID" datePattern="d/M/yy HH:mm" style="width:200px"/>
```

Is this the right way to enable the time field or am i missing something?
I am using RichFaces 3.3.1 and JSF 1.2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems perfect..! Have you selected any date ? time field will come once you select date.

Comment: hi, once when i select the date, the calendar dialog closes and hence i could not see the time field enabled. Above code is working fine.!